# What does php-fpm tainted mean?

Tags: php, server, fastcgi

I'm having server troubles.  Website goes down and up repeatedly. After checking server processes, this constantly keeps coming up. e.g.

**Jan  3 23:30:05 website kernel: CPU: 10 PID: 22345 Comm: php-fpm Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-77-generic #89~10.03.1-Ubuntu**

What does php-fpm tainted meaning?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux servers. [sf] would be a better place for questions like this.

Comment: I think it's your OS which is Tainted, not the php-fpm. Take a look at these two links which may help [What is a tainted kernel in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118117/119479) and [Why does my server freeze everyday at the same time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161521/why-does-my-server-freeze-everyday-at-the-same-time)